# Autofill 2 Fields on a Web Page with C#

Tags: c#, autofill

I am working on a simple web forms application with C# (Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express).

I have two text boxes (textBox1, richTextBox1) a button (button1) and a web browser (webBrowser1) on the form. The web browser goes to a web page when I run the program. On that page there are two input fields that I want to autofill with the click of the button1 using the text in textBox1 and richTextBox1.

You can see the code of the input fields on that web page:

```
<input type="text" id="subject" tabindex="4" name="subject" value="">

<textarea class="composebody" tabindex="6" name="message" id="message" rows="20" cols="80"></textarea>
```

I know this is very simple, but I don't have much knowledge about C#. Any ideas how I can code that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write this code

webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("subject").SetAttribute("value", subject.text);
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("msg").SetAttribute("value",message.text );

and need to call those two lines in
DocumentCompleted event of webbrowser.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Ajay, since I want the fields to be filled when I click the button I used the code you gave with the click event of the button.

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("subject").SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
            webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("message").SetAttribute("value", richTextBox1.Text);
        }

And it works exactly as I want it now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the following:

```
subject.value = "Your info here";
```

This will solve the issue for your first item but the text area is a bit more tricky.  You will probably need to include some HTML item inside the text area that you can write to.  I was not able to find a good way to write to the textarea item easily.  If possible, I would suggest using a different control.