# Control web session using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a web portal that I'm trying to pass information to another website.  When the user clicks on a link I'd like to load the new web page and stuff the two form fields with information then SUBMIT to automate a process.

I found this: [Autofill 2 Fields on a Web Page with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907516/autofill-2-fields-on-a-web-page-with-c-sharp)

However, this assumes I open a new webbrowser control but instead I want to use the current web session.

Is this possible or is there another way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you modify the second web page?

Comment: No unfortunately not...

Answer (score 1):

Use WebClient class. Place it inside onclick event of your link.

```
var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
string url = "www.mysite.com?a=xyz&b=123";

cli.Downloadstring(url);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for..?  The site I want to fill in the form is outside of my control.

A user goes into my portal clicks on a link (MVC web site) pointing to the outside website.  That site is where I want to fill in two textboxes.